# partial derivative with respect to the entry of the associated endomorphism of metric

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, kahler-manifolds

I am currently reading a paper about PDE analysis over Kahler manifold. I am struggling for the meaning of a structural condition.

Let $X$ be a compact Kahler manifold without boundary of dimension n, and $\omega_X$ its
K ̈ahler form. If $\varphi$ is a real smooth function on $X$, we let $\omega_\varphi = \omega_X+\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar{\partial}\varphi$, and let $h_\varphi$
be the corresponding endomorphism relative to the metric $\omega_X$ . Explicitly, if we write
$\omega_X = \sqrt{-1}g _{\bar{k}j} dz^j \wedge d\bar{z}^k$ in local holomorphic coordinates, then $(h_\varphi)^j_k = g^j_\bar{m}(\omega_\varphi)_{\bar{m}k}$. Let $λ[h_\varphi]$
be the vector of eigenvalues of $h_\varphi$, and consider the non-linear partial differential equation. $$f(\lambda[h_\varphi])=e^F, \sup_X \varphi=0, \lambda[h_\varphi]\in\Gamma\dots(1)$$

$f$ are smooth function invariant under permutation of component and homogeneous one. $\Gamma$ is a cone such that $\{\lambda:\lambda_1>0,\dots,\lambda_n>0\}\subset \Gamma\subset\{\lambda:\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_n>0\}$ with $\dfrac{df}{d\lambda}>0$ for $\lambda\in \Gamma$

Then a theorem states that

**Theorem**

Consider equation $(1)$,a nd assume the function $f(\lambda)$ satisfy the following structural condition, namely there exists a $\gamma>0$ so that $$\det\left(\dfrac{\partial(f(\lambda[h]))}{\partial h_{ij}}\right)\ge \gamma, \text{for all } \lambda\in\Gamma$$ then sth sth we can conclude.

I do not really understand the part-taking derivative w.r.t $h_{ij}$ means, as $h$ is hermitian which implies diagonalizable and real eigenvalues. If I just change one entry, the new matrix may not Hermitian matrix. After that $f$ at most have $n$-th entry, the jacobian matrix probably is not a square matrix. How could it make sense in determinant?